# Is tax owed on money sent to India through an NRO account?

Tags: taxes, india, non-resident, saudi-arabia

I need to transfer money from my Saudi account (NCB)  to India through my own NRO account. Should I have to pay tax for this transaction?

Answer (score 1):

Taxability depends on your tax residency status.

Assuming you are non-resident Indian for tax purposes, then your income is non taxable in India.

If you keep the money in Saudi or transfer to India it would be same and non taxable